# React Full Calendar disable header button

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I added a custom button to my header to 'undo' actions in my calendar. It is working fine, but I cant find out how to disable my custom button when there are no events in my action history.

For now, I just skip my actions in the handler, but I want to customize my button to LOOK disabled.

There seems to be, since full calendar implements a disabled button for 'previous month', as shown in the example.
[image]

Is there any way I can achieve this?

I'm using full calendar v4.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is possible.